# react-native-maps : How to get dynamic latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta values upon zoom-in and zoom-out

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, zooming, react-native-maps

I have a specific requirement to display a polygon and a marker in map.
When zoom-in, I display a polygon and multiple marker pin. But zoom-out i should use same polygon but display only 1 marker on it.

`Current behavior` : even while zoom-out when polygon becomes tiny  it displays multiple markers on it.

[image]

`Expected Behaviour` : When it is zoom out only one marker should be visible. When it is zoomed in then all marker should be visible like below: Can someone help me fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using `onRegionChangeComplete` function of  element.

Following is the code:

```
onRegionChangeComplete = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      region: e,
    });
  };
```